# Dynamically use Active Record includes on the appropriate associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model call entities which belongs to lets say either Machine, Assembly or Component. My associations is as follows:

entity.rb

```
belongs_to :work_orderable, polymorphic: true
```

machine.rb, subassembly.rb, component.rb

```
has_many :entities, as: :work_orderable, dependent: :destroy
```

Now i want to query on entity model for an attribute of work_orderable using includes. 
Im using this query currently which is very slow :

```
 ids = @work_orders.includes(:work_orderable).select { |work_order| work_order.work_orderable.responsibility.include?(@current_user.id) }.map(&:id)
  # @work_orders.where('id IN (?)', ids)
```

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: responsibility is a association or an attribute holding user id.

Comment: responsiblity is an attribute of work_orderable